# asymptotic order in probability

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics

Consider the definition of [small o in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation#Comparison_of_the_two_definitions).

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables and let $X_n=1+o_p(1)$. That is, for any $\delta,\epsilon>0: P(\lvert X_n-1\rvert\geq \delta)\leq \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. The sequence converges in probability to one.

This led me to conjecture that there should be a constant $1>M>0$ so that $P(\lvert X_n\rvert\geq M)\to1$ as $n\to+\infty$. Or equivalently, $P(\lvert X_n\rvert < M)\to 0$ .

**Question**. If it is true, then how to prove it?

Comment: You’re asking whether convergence in probability to $1$ implies convergence in distribution to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|X_n-1|\le \epsilon)=\mathsf{P}(1-\epsilon\le X_n\le 1+\epsilon)\to 1
$$
as $n\to\infty$, which implies that for any $M<1$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|X_n| \ge M)\ge \mathsf{P}(X_n \ge M)\to 1.
$$

Comment: Wait, can you explain me the last line? why the first expression implies the second?

Comment: Ok, as $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, any $M<1$ works.

Comment: @CelineHarumi That's correct. You can also notice that $F_{X_n}(x)$ converges to $1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$, which leads to the same conclusion: any $M<1$ works.